# Spellchecker extension for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, spell-check

Chrome's spell checker is inferior to Google Search's. For example, it suggest I replace "recommendatation" with "recommendatory" where as Google Search will identify I actually mean "recommendation".

Is there an extension to Chrome that uses Google Search to offer better spelling suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't use Google Search spelling recommendations but have you tried the [After The Deadline spelling/grammar extension](http://chrome.afterthedeadline.com/)?

> After the Deadline checks spelling, misused words, style, and grammar using artificial intelligence and natural language processing.